# Escaping the '\' character in the replacement string in a sed expression

Tags: bash, string, sed, escaping

I am trying to take a line of text like

```
    13) Check for orphaned Path entries
```

and change it to (I want the bash color codes to colorize the output, not display on the screen)

```
\033[32m*\033[0m Check for orphaned Path entries
```

with bash color codes to colorize the asterisk to make it stand out more.  I have a sed command that does most of that, except it doesn't handle the color codes correctly since it sees them as references to replacement text.

What I have so far:

```
sed "s/ *13) \(.*\)/ \033[32m*\033[0m \1/"
```

which produces the following output when run on the string I gave at the beginning:

```
   13) Check for orphaned Path entries33[32m*  13) Check for orphaned Path entries33[0m Check for orphaned Path entries
```

It is taking the \0 of the \033 and replacing it with the original string.  Doubling the backslashes in the replacement string doesn't make a difference; I still get the same output text.

How do I insert bash color escapes into a sed replacement expression?

Comment: Quadrupling the backslashes caused the same effect as using single quotes and doubled bashslashes, as suggested by @DreadPirateShawn.  I get \033[32m*\033[0m output directly to the console, without being turned into color codes.

Comment: It's basically the same thing. That's why I head already deleted my comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Chances are that the `sed` you are using doesn't understand octal, but it may understand hex. Try this version to see if it works for you (using `\x1b` instead of `\033`):

```
sed "s/ *13) \(.*\)/ \x1b[32m*\x1b[0m \1/"
```

Comment: if it does grok octal, use \o033

Comment: @Hasturkun: That's why it pays to read the info file. Sometimes man just doesn't cut it. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Dennis: Do you mean that sometimes man does not have the same manual as info?

Answer (score 8):

your '\033' is in fact a single `ESC` (escape) character, to output this you may use any one of the following:

- `\o033`
- `\d027`
- `\x1B`
- `\c[` for `CTRL-[`

Comment: +1 for the octal prefix - most programs just recognize the leading zero.

Answer (score 3):

Double the backslashes in the replacement string, AND use single instead of double quotes around the sed expression:

```
sed 's/ *13) \(.*\)/ \\033[32m*\\033[0m \1/'
```

This prevents the shell from interfering with the sed behaviour.

~~~~~~~

Update:

Use a script to achieve color cleanly:

colorize.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

HIGHLIGHT=`echo -e '\033[32m'`
NORMAL=`echo -e '\033[0m'`

sed "s/ *13) \(.*\)/ $HIGHLIGHT*$NORMAL \1/" yourinputtext
```

Comment: While sed isn't trying to replace the \0 now, I'm still not getting colored output.

Comment: To be more specific, I get \033[32m*\033[0m output directly to the console, without being turned into color codes

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean... My aim was to solve the problem of escaping the '\' character in the replacement string, and did so -- I get the same output text you cite in your "change it to" string above. Beyond that, you know what you're looking for color-wise more than I do; just wanted to make sure you had the tools nailed down to do so. :-)

Comment: Just saw your update -- I misunderstood your "change it to" string, then... thought that's what you wanted to output. Hmm...

Comment: PS - My script works, but Dennis Williamson's answer accomplishes the same thing, and is far shorter. Use his.

Comment: Sorry for dulpicating your answer. I missed the back-ticks (and the echoes). That's one of the reasons I always use $() - improved readability since there's no confusion with single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved in this way.

You can try to change your code:

```
sed "s/ *13) \(.*\)/ \033[32m*\033[0m \1/"
```

into this:

```
sed "s/ *13) \(.*\)/ $(echo '\033[32m')*$(echo '\033[0m') \1/"
```

The basic idea is to use 'echo' to print the escape command.
It worked for me,

Answer (score 0):

I use gawk

```
gawk -v string1=$STRING1 -v IGNORECASE=1 ' { gsub ( string1 , "\033[1m&\033[0m" ) ; print } '
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
sed  "s/ *13) \(.*\)/ \\\\033 \1/"
```

i.e. slash-slash-slash-slash-033