# Use sed to add background color to tabs?

Tags: linux, unix, sed

Is possible to use sed to change the background color of tabs (or any other text), so that, for example, I could run something like the following?

```
somefunction | sed -e 's/(some pattern)/(set bg color)\1(unset bg color)/g'
```

Comment: yes, this is possible. i hope someone comes along and gives you the answer, because I'm not at the computer where I am doing this right now and can't remember how I did it. something to do with terminal control codes, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes:

```
#!/bin/bash

norm_bg=$(tput sgr0)
red_bg=$(tput setab 1)

echo -e "foo\tbar\tbaz" | sed "s/\t/$red_bg    $norm_bg/g"
```

See this link for other [**Color Codes**](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-shell-change-the-color-of-my-shell-prompt-under-linux-or-unix/) (very bottom)

[image: terminal]

Answer (score 5):

You can insert colorization directly within your `sed` script:

```
echo -e "foo\tbar\tbaz" | sed 's/\t/\o033[41m    \o033[0m/g'
```

**Explanation:**

- set background in red = `\o033[41m` or `\x1B[41m` or `\c[[41m`
- reset colors = `\o033[0m` or `\x1B[0m` or `\c[[0m`

You can also read similar question/anwsers: 
[Escaping the '\' character in the replacement string in a sed expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064352).

For more info on color codes, refer to [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt#List_of_colors_for_prompt_and_Bash).

Answer (score 3):

+1 for olibre.

This also works on osx and linux, bash and zsh using [extquote](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/internals/shell_options#extquote).

```
echo My name is Chad. | sed -e 's/Chad/\'$'\033[31m&\033[(B\033[m/'
```

Comment: +1 for you too ;-) Very good idea to use extquote in this situation: you do not have to remember the specific `sed` way to handle special characters. I will reuse your tip ;-) Cheers